# "basic" listView adapter question

Tags: android

I have a listview where each row is composed of a textview and an imageview. I want to set the visibility of the imageview when the adapter is created. following is the relevant piece of code where i am trying to just SET the 3rd row's imageview to VISIBLE state (by default, all are set to INVISIBLE in my lis_item_icon_text.xml file that is inflated). Can you pls tell me how to achieve this? TIA.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);              
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.text.setText(data_text_array[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon);
        if(position == 3) {
            holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }
```

Comment: What is the behavior or the app currently? is every image showing, not showing, or is it just crashing?

Comment: I agree with Woodszy. This looks like it should work, wo unless we know what is happening otherwise, we will not be able to help.

Comment: @Woodszy @AedonEtLIRA The behavior currently is this - the first and the fourth row's imageViews are made VISIBLE and each time i scroll thro' my list, more and more of the row's imageViews are set to VISIBLE too. there is no order to what is being set or unset. No crashes or force closes. I am testing on a 3.0 Honeycomb device

Comment: This might be overkill but I had a similar issue once with a textview style being "sticky" so I had to add an else statement to reset the defaults. try adding else{holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}

Comment: @Woodszy that trick works for this case where we are setting the state for one row. but if we had a long list of items and if we were reading the states from a database/persistent-storage, do you think setting the "else INVISIBLE" clause would step on the others' "if VISIBLE" clause? thanks again.

Comment: @Woodszy i verified that your suggestion actually works even for a larger set of data. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

remove condition if (convertView == null) and compare position==2 instead of position==3 (bcoz positioning starts from 0 ) .

so ur code will be :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);  

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.text.setText(data_text_array[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon);
        if(position == 2) {
            holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }
```

Comment: without the (convertView == null), we would be inflating the row item everythime getView is called and i don't think that might be the right thing to do

Comment: Right ...... bt 2 not inflating is d actual problem here ...means if you r making any changes in layout like visibility ect ,it will persist dis for next ro and result wd b unexpected combination , so i think dis is d only way .